# What are methods in OOP?

Tags: java, oop

In *Head First Java*, they define methods as "things that an object can do".

Let's say I have a object named button. A button should not be able to set its own label or color because that is supposed to done by some other object. Another object tells the button to set the button's text or color.

So why do buttons have methods like setText?

Comment: But a Button in programming can have it's label set, can't it? :)

Comment: Yes a button can have label and color as propery.But i am not sure if button object should have methods named setButtonLabel.since it sounds confusing as per defination of method.After all a button is a dumb object it can not do any thing

Comment: I think the people who downvote this kind of question need to be reminded that at some point in their lives, they were ignorant of a lot of things as well.

Comment: @Tarun take a look at the [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) documentation. A whole bunch of methods there deal with changing the button's state - including `setLabel()`! so yes, it's perfectly reasonable to have a "dumb object" do things with methods!

Comment: @Tarun come to think of it, that definition is quite strange. If not simply wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods in a class represent the *behavior* of an object, as opposed to the attributes - which represent the object's data. Of course, it'd be correct to have a `setButtonLabel` method, whose behavior is changing the state of the button's label.

And the statement "A button can not set label or color for itself" is false, an object can change its own state from another method, although clearly at some point the change has to be started from an external object.

Comment: But if we compare oops to real world , then should not button be a dumb object and it should not have such methods(Ability what object can do) like setButtonLabel.

Comment: An object must contain all the methods that deal with its own data - only the button is responsible for knowing how to change or retrieve its own label, color, etc. so that others can ask from it: "hey, button change your label". The whole idea of OO is encapsulating data and the operations over _that_ data on the same object